# What happens to inequalities when $\epsilon$ $\to$ $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

I recently came across a proof in topology. There was an inequality in which 
$A$$<$$B$ + $\epsilon$ (strictly less than),But when $\epsilon$ $\to$ $0$ , then it was inferred that $A$<=$B$.

Here $B$ is the infimum of a sequence and we are using the basic definition of infimum.(There is always a number between infimum and infimum + $\epsilon$)

How is this possible?

Comment: I think we will need a bit more context. What are $A$ and $B$, exactly? The infimum of what sequence?

Comment: For future reference, please refrain from using ALL CAPS in a single sentence. There's a high chance your question would be viewed as low quality by some.

Comment: @BigbearZzz thanks, will make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A<B+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, then we can conclude that $A\leq B$. In fact, this is the **most** you can conclude. It is in fact rather easy to prove the following statement:

> $A$ is less than or equal to $B$ if and only if, for all $\epsilon>0$, $A$ is less than $B+\epsilon$. In symbols, this is:
>   $$(A\leq B) \iff (\forall \epsilon > 0: A<B+\epsilon)$$

We cannot conclude that $A<B$, and we cannot conclude $A=B$.

Comment: Thanks, will make the edit, I found out that indeed the statement you provided was the actual doubt.

Comment: Can you give the proof for the statement you provided.

Comment: @Cosmic I think it's good practice if you try to prove it yourself!

Comment: Will try doing that

Comment: @Cosmic The proof to the right is fairly straightforward. Proving to the left is best done through a proof by contradiction (or more simply, contrapositive)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misguided.

In general, for any $a,b\in\Bbb R$ such that $a<b+\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, we can deduce only that $a\le b$. Indeed, to prove the claim we can assume  that $a>b$ and take $\varepsilon=\frac {a-b}2$ to get a contradiction.

Since I've seen you used the tag measure theory I'll assume further about how the proof you've seen conclude $a=b$ . Normally, when you want to prove that $a=b$ you'd need to show that $a\ge b$ and $a\le b$. In measure theory, it is often the case that the $a\ge b$ direction is obvious or easy to show, hence you only need to do the other half. Proving $a\le b$ directly could still be difficult, hence we instead prove that $a<b+\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ and then deduce that $a\le b$.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that it was the case in the question.

Comment: @GitGud Right, thank you I'll make the edit.